# Error compiling equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, physics

My document (subfile in documentclass book) compiles perfectly, untill I add the following equation:

```
\begin{equation} 
\label{beliefupdate}
\begin{split}
b_{t+1}(s') & = \Pr(s'|o',a,b) \\
            & = \frac{\Pr(o'|s',a,b)\Pr(s'|a,b)}{\Pr(o'|a,b} \\
            & = \frac{\Pr(o'|s',a) \sum_{s\in\S}\Pr(s'|a,b,s)\Pr(s|a,b)}{\Pr(o'|a,b)} \\
            & = \frac{O(o',a,s') \sum_{s\in\S}T(s,a,s')b_t(s)}{\Pr(o'|a,b)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I have loaded the packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{physics}

\renewcommand{\S}{\mathcal{S}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

Now, Latex starts giving me warnings in two locations of the document. The first few are in this piece of code, way before the location where I enter the equation

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.25]{images/MDP.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I get the error: 'missing number, treated as zero'  and also 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' both about the line  \centering

The second batch of errors is about the line \end{split} in the equation.

errors:

FIRST ERROR:

Argument of \opbraces has an extra }.

\par 
l.151 \end{split}

---

SECOND ERROR:

Runaway argument?

(o'|a,b
! Paragraph ended before \opbraces  was complete.

\par
l.151 \end{split}

---

THIRD ERROR:
Missing $ inserted.

---

I honestly don't see where I go wrong

Comment: Don't use `physics`.

Comment: Well, that seemed to work. Thanks haha! Any explanation why, because I would never have figured this out myself

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to replace the "conditioning" uses of `|` with `\mid`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you're missing `)` at the end of the second line in `split`:

```
        & = \frac{\Pr(o'|s',a,b)\Pr(s'|a,b)}{\Pr(o'|a,b} \\
```

should be

```
        & = \frac{\Pr(o'|s',a,b)\Pr(s'|a,b)}{\Pr(o'|a,b)} \\
```

The missing parenthesis goes unnoticed when `physics` is not loaded, but it becomes essential when it is, because the package (re)defines `\Pr` to look for an argument enclosed in `(...)` (which is a bad thing to do, in my opinion).

Check your input more closely. And don't do `\renewcommand\S{\mathcal{S}}`.

<sub>**Personal opinion.** I cannot recommend using the `physics` package, because it has a very convoluted syntax and makes disputable typesetting decisions.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. It is sloppy that i overlooked the parenthesis. Any comment on why not to renewcommand? because it  is error prone? By the way, I would upvote your post, but apparently I can't because I lack the reputation

Comment: @Rens it is better to never redefine internal commands, and it's better to not use one-letter commands, they are used internally often, and changing them can have very strange effects.   For example `\S` is normally defined (barring the protect) as: `\S :
\long macro:->\ifmmode \mathsection \else \textsection \fi`  ---  you never know where it can bite you

Comment: @Rens I can confirm what Rmano says; use `\cS` or whatever, but don't redefine commands you don't know about. A colleague of mine had all sorts of mysterious error messages because he had redefined `\c`.

Comment: Clear! Thanks again for the answers